# Get back to gnome/Enlightenment from the command line

Tags: gnome, command-line, enlightenment

So say I accidentally hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> and drop to the commandline from my nice clean engligntenment interface. How do I then get back?

I've tried startX, Xwindows, gnome but none of those commands seem to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to restart Enlightenment by opening a command line and running the following command:

`/usr/bin/enlightenment_start &`